# Best practices for H1 tag on a portfolio site

Tags: html, css

*I've tried a lot of searching and while I have gained some info I don't have conclusive answers. Most articles on the h1 tag are about blog posts with regard to the page title (h1 tags not title tags), whereas I'm looking for something on a portfolio/business site where page titles are not as obvious.*

Up to now I have been giving the business name the h1 tag. I realized the business name would be better as an image logo so I changed this but now I'm not sure what to do with the h1 tag.

**How do I use the h1 tag for SEO and not have it clutter the page? Hide it?**

I would like the h1 tag to be closer to the page title tag, but this feels cumbersome and too "sales pitchy" on the page. **Effectively what I would like to communicate to search engines is a clearer pitch than is needed for communicating to humans landing on the page.**

Here's an example:

```
<title>Interior Designer | Based in Hawaii | John Sparks</title>

<logo image>John Sparks</logo image>
<subtitle>Interior Designer</subtitle> <!--Much cleaner and friendlier for the user but not great for SEO-->

<h1>Hawaii based Interior Designer for hire</h1> <!--Better for SEO but not wanted on the page-->
```

Additionally, what is best practice for the *about* and *contact* pages regarding the h1 tag? It seems to me that only the index page is necessary for search engines, so does it matter?

Comment: _Element_, not tag. Tags are text in a file.

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for SO. It's about SEO and not coding. Please take the [tour].

Comment: SEO fits coding somewhat, since it's driven by the right code metadata. Still, it seems to me like OP is confused about what he's asking in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If your only focus for page title is SEO, don't use `<h1>`, and instead use page metadata using the Open Graph Protocol:
https://ogp.me/

```html
<html prefix="og: https://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

Both the `<title>Title</title>` tag and `<meta property="og:title" content="..." />` do a better job of communicating the page's title to Search Engines than a `<h1>`

Google has some great documentation on page titles using the `<title>` tag:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/appearance/title-link

To learn more about the Open Graph Protocol and how to make search engines and social media understand your page better, Google also has a great introductory course here:
https://web.dev/social-discovery/

Comment: So do you mean in the instance I'm describing there's no point in using <h1>? I am slightly confused about what I'm asking, I have been under the assumption that <h1> is an important part of the page, I don't want to hurt a business by not making best use of it.

Comment: `h1` are no more significant on a page than other sections in it. Semantically, it will tell SEO engines that there is a section heading but that's about it.  For SEO, it might make a minuscule difference, if any at all.  The notion that SEO will consider it an important part of the page has little weight, IMHO.

Comment: correct @calid , and blurfus is correct. If you have further SEO related questions, Stack Overflow is not the correct platform to be asking those questions I'm afraid. Both links I provided in the answer above should at the very least address your concern as to what is important for SEO page header labeling (notice none of it mentions <h1> anywhere)

Comment: Ah okay got. Stack Overflow is generally the first place I go for answers, I check other places too, so I tend to ask questions here as I'm not any other other platform. I will keep that in mind next time. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, that's fair. Glad to help. SO is a great place, but it's strict rule set while making it a fantastic place to get quick Q&A answers, is not a great place for more nuanced or theoretical discussion. Try Web Development Discord channels like DevCord and The Programmer's Hangout, you might have better luck there. Good luck! @calid